# Where to post free-time job offers?

Tags: discussion, jobs, job-offers

I'm part of a small browser game where all team members including developers are free time "workers" without getting money. We are in need of a 3D graphic developer for several months now but didn't have any luck with postings in (german) graphics forums or with flyers at some universities. Therefore I thought of posting a "job announcement" in the Stack Exchange network.

It is at this point that I am unsure as to how to proceed. Where is a good place to search for people like students or pupils (and of course other people who want to help for fun) in the network? And is there such a place at all?

My first thought was Careers, but I noticed that it's a place for real paid jobs and the prices are to expensive for a small free-time game like we are. Another thought was Graphic Design, but I didn't want to risk posting there because it seems to be the Stack Overflow of graphic design. Same for Game Development (aside from the fact that game development aims more for game mechanisms in my opinion than programming or graphics).

Is there a place to post such job announcements in the Stack Exchange network or is Stack Exchange only suitable for 'real' questions?

Comment: Write like this on your profile description section. `Hey i wanna a 3D Graphic developer and i would like to  pay blah dollars per month. IF you're willing to join in my company, please contact me via blah@foo.com email or send your resume to this email-id` . Don't forget to mention the company location.

Comment: Another option would be to hang up a post/notice in the next university or college near you that teach game-design, graphic-design etc..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Stack Exchange is a lot of things, but I fear a competitor to Craigslist it is not.

In other words, yes, it is "only suitable for 'real' questions." Your thinking that Graphic Design is the "Stack Overflow of graphic design" is pretty well-founded, since most of the principles of Stack Overflow do follow across the entire network, and with pretty good reason.

Careers is an awesome choice, but I recognized that you've already thought about that and ruled it out for price reasons. Beyond that, I fear there just won't be any good choice.

You *might* try asking on some per-site metas about their rules for [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com), but realistically I doubt that most will allow anything there, either. A post like you're talking about could be considered somewhat spammy, so it's unlikely to be well-received.

In general with stuff like this, think of how the site would feel if *everyone* started doing it.

Comment: "If everyone started doing this"??? = hell on earth... an SE informercial...gah!

Answer (score 6):

You could get some attention by the SE community promotion ads, that is for open source projects that get free attention for their contribution to the community.

I think though, that you need a neat open source project to get there, but it might be worth a try.

For what the SE sites concerns: there is no site suitable for this.